Fan Problem in dual booted Ubuntu
I have dual booted my Hp Omen 16(ryzen 7840,4050 gpu) with the latest Ubuntu and Windows 11. The fans seem to run just fine on windows but on ubuntu they dont speed up even when the temprature is getting higher. In the terminal i ran the sensors command:
 $ sensors
mdgpu-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:        1.43 V  
vddnb:       668.00 mV 
edge:         +38.0°C  
PPT:          23.20 W  (avg =   6.05 W)

hp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
fan2:           0 RPM

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          13.21 V  

mt7921_phy0-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +50.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +38.9°C  

nvme-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +38.9°C  (low  = -40.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +87.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +51.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +38.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +38.0°C  
temp2:       -273.2°C  

I dont think those tempratures are even possible and i can confirm the fans are spinning. I have also tried the command sensors-detect but at the end it says:
$ sudo sensors-detect
Sorry, no sensors were detected.
This is relatively common on laptops, where thermal management is
handled by ACPI rather than the OS.

